# How to get overlapped rectangular bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create 3 layers of rectangles each with different color on top of each other to get something like below image:

[image]

**Data:**

```
library(tidyverse)

df_vaccination <- data.frame(type = c('Population', 'First.Dose.Administered', 'Second.Dose.Administered'),
           count = c(1366400000, 952457943, 734608556))
```

**Code tried:**

```
df_vaccination %>% 
  
  ggplot()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = count, ymax = 0,
                   size = 10, lineend = 'round',
                   alpha = 0.5, fill = type)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#d8b365", "orange", "#5ab4ac")) +
  
  theme_clean() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = unit_format(scale = 1e-7, unit = "Cr")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1),
         size = FALSE,
         alpha = FALSE)
```

Result I am getting is blank plot when I am using **geom_rect()** & **scale_fill_manual()**. I am not sure why am I getting blank rectangle:
[image]

Comment: Your bars have zero height, i.e. `ymax = 0` and `ymin = 0` produce invisible rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert *type* column to ordered factor so that largest number plots first, then use *geom_col* with *x = 1*. This will make the bars to plot on top of each other, lastly flip the coordinates:

```
df_vaccination$type <- factor(df_vaccination$type, levels = df_vaccination$type)

ggplot(df_vaccination, aes(x = 1, y = count, fill = type))+
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#d8b365", "orange", "#5ab4ac")) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]